# Jackson: how to get rid of the namespace prefixes... (or Numbers in a string are omitted by XML serialization)

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize a POJO as XML. I am using the default Serializer and bumped into an unexpected issue with strings containing numbers: they just disapear from the final XML produced by Jackson.

These are 2 samples of POJO's; as you can see they are nested (the root element is missing here):

```
package configuration.system;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Authentication {

    private User user;

    @JsonProperty("oauth2-client")
    private OAuth2Client oAuth2Client;

}
```

```
package configuration.system;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private static final String GROUPS_NS = "urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext";

    private final String name;

    private final String password;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = GROUPS_NS)
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> groups;

}
```

```
package configuration.system;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JsonPropertyOrder({"client-id", "client-secret","groups"})
public class OAuth2Client {

    @JsonCreator
    public OAuth2Client(final String clientId, final String clientSecret , final List<String> groups) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "client-id")
    private final String clientId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "client-secret")
    private final String clientSecret;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private final List<String> groups;

}
```

And all elements are correctly parsed and serialized as expected, producing this output:

```
<system>
  <authentication>
    <user>
      <name>admin</name>
      <password>p$Wrd</password>
      <groups xmlns="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv1-admin</groups>
      <groups xmlns="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv2-admin</groups>
      <groups xmlns="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">system-admin</groups>
      <groups xmlns="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv3-admin</groups>
    </user>
    <oauth-client>
      <client-id>clientId</client-id>
      <client-secret>acf-feb-eb-b-acb</client-secret>
      <groups>scopes/system.read</groups>
      <groups>scopes/system.write</groups>
    </oauth-client>
  </authentication>
</system>
```

But when I wrote a TC to check that the serialized content matched the expected XML failed, reason being that:

- user.password = p4$W0rd
- oauth2-client.clientId = 7acf0054-f1eb-4e1b-b304-8a587c9292b6

but, as you can see, the resulting strings from the serialization are, precisely, those set above but missing numbers.
The code to serialize is as follows:

```
protected Optional<String> serializeInternal(final SerializationOutput outputFormat) {
        final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        if (outputFormat == SerializationOutput.FORMATTED) {
            xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        }

        xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLInputFactory().setProperty(WstxInputProperties.P_RETURN_NULL_FOR_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE,
                true);
        xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX, NO_NS_PREFIX);
        try {
            return Optional.of(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(this).replaceAll(":*[0-9]+:*", ""));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Serialization of {} as XML failed", this.getClass().getName());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

I have tried several serialization properties without any result, some of them should not produce any result, I know, but just for trying:

- use of @JsonRawValue
- use of @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)

I'd like to avoid coming up with a customized serializer just for this, because those strings do not have anything I should handle in a special way during serialization, and this I guess should come out of the box.
Any hint is appreciated, since I don't know what else to check.
Thanks.

This is added after the answer by @user3696953. The original 'problem' was the attempt to remove the namespace prefixes. As you can see, the  element is namespaced. This is achieved with the `@JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = GROUPS_NS)` annotation in the `groups` field of the User POJO.
With that, the serialization yields:

```
<user>
      <name>admin</name>
      <password>p4$W0rd</password>
      <wstxns1:groups xmlns:wstxns1="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv1-admin</wstxns1:groups>
      <wstxns2:groups xmlns:wstxns2="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv2-admin</wstxns2:groups>
      <wstxns3:groups xmlns:wstxns3="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">system-admin</wstxns3:groups>
      <wstxns4:groups xmlns:wstxns4="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv3-admin</wstxns4:groups>
    </user>
```

Then I found the way to disable the default namespace prefixing, which is not directly supported by Jackson, by the way, but has to be directly set in the Output factory using a Stax API property. This is the purpose of the line `xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX, NO_NS_PREFIX);` in the serialization code, where `P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX` holds the name of the Stax property to control the automatic prefix (org.codehaus.stax2.automaticNsPrefix) and `NO_NS_PREFIX` is just "":

```
protected Optional<String> serializeInternal(final SerializationOutput outputFormat) {
        final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        if (outputFormat == SerializationOutput.FORMATTED) {
            xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        }

        xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLInputFactory().setProperty(WstxInputProperties.P_RETURN_NULL_FOR_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE,
                true);
        xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX, NO_NS_PREFIX);
        try {
            return Optional.of(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(this));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error(
                    "Serialization of {} as XML failed" + System.lineSeparator() + "Cause is: {}"
                            + System.lineSeparator() + "Message: {}",
                    this.getClass().getName(), e.getCause(), e.getMessage());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

Afther this the serialization results in:

```
<user>
      <name>admin</name>
      <password>p4$W0rd</password>
      <1:groups xmlns:1="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv1-admin</1:groups>
      <2:groups xmlns:2="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nvf2-admin</2:groups>
      <3:groups xmlns:3="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">system-admin</3:groups>
      <4:groups xmlns:4="urn:rdns:com:oammodel:system-ext">nfv3-admin</4:groups>
    </user>
```

Closer, but not yet there. The regex to replace the numbers was the problem cusing the original question (my blindness), but the bottom question here is **how to get rid of the sequencing numbers of elements present multiple times?**

Answer (score 1):

Your not getting any numbers because on this line below you are using a regex expression to replace all instances of numbers with no character instead

```
return Optional.of(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(this).replaceAll(":*[0-9]+:*", ""));
```

I don't know what your intent was for using this replaceAll() method but, you need to resolve the `.replaceAll(":*[0-9]+:*", "")` method to be removed or replaced with whatever it is you were actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I feel embarrased :-)... You can imagine how much shame I have felt when I read your answer... And I have gone through these lines tens of times. The reason for that replace is to remove the remains of the namespace prefix, which is, indeed, the bottom line question. I will edit the question to explain better. Thanks!